# How to reorder lines of a file using a for loop and array using awk

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, file-io, awk

I have a situation in which I need to take an input file, reorder its lines by an order that is not determinable from the file but from an order that I can specify, then output the new order into a new file.

**Input file** (content changed for demonstration)

```
This should be line four
This should be line six
This should be line three
This should be line two
This should be line seven
This should be line one
This should be line five
```

**Expected output file**

```
This should be line one
This should be line two
...
This should be line seven
```

I thought awk may be the best approach, and that storing the desired order in an array then looping through it and pulling out the relative line might work.

I have written the following to establish the array and loop through it, printing the line numbers in the order the output should be:

```
awk 'BEGIN { split("4 6 3 2 7 1 5",n); for(i=1; i<=7; i++) print n[i] }'
```

Output:

```
4
6
3
2
7
1
5
```

Having used NR previously I thought I may be able to simply substitute `print n[i]` for `NR==n[i]` but this results in no errors but also a blank output.txt

```
awk 'BEGIN { split("4 6 3 2 7 1 5",n); for(i=1; i<=7; i++) NR==n[i] }' file.txt > output.txt
```

I'm looking for the most elegant solution to either successfully adapt my final attempt above to print the relative line numbers of file.txt into output.txt as per the array, or a better approach as a whole that I may not be aware of.

Comment: the sequence number `4, 6, 3,2...` is known information?

Comment: Yes that's known information for this particular file, apologies if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{split("4 6 3 2 7 1 5",n)} {a[NR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i in n;i++) print a[n[i]]}' file.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I ended up with a similar command as you at first, but I think the sequences actually need to be corrected to get the expected output -> `6 4 3 1 7 2 5`.  At least they did for me using gawk version 3.1.5.

Comment: @n0741337 Right, the posted expected output does not match the sample input given the order of lines specified in the sample script. I just went with the order in the script figuring the OP can change it easily enough to whatever (s)he wants.

Comment: @EdMorton Exactly what I was looking for, a great extension of where I'd gotten to. Produced the perfect output as is. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am confused about expected output and o/p shown by others

One easy way I don't know whether you like or not

```
akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat file
This should be line four
This should be line six
This should be line three
This should be line two
This should be line seven
This should be line one
This should be line five

akshay@Aix:/tmp$ cat seq
4
6
3
2
7
1
5

akshay@Aix:/tmp$ paste seq file | sort -nk1 | sed 's/^[0-9]*\s//'
This should be line one
This should be line two
This should be line three
This should be line four
This should be line five
This should be line six
This should be line seven
```

Comment: Cute approach so +1. No need for the `k1` on the sort, though, since theres no duplicates in the first field and I'd use `cut -f2-` instead of sed so it'd be a bit more concise: `paste seq file | sort -n | cut -f2-`.

Comment: oh! just saw your answer, I posted a very similar solution.  note that, it is better define a delimiter in `paste`, and in `sed` remove from beginning till (inclusive) that delimiter. think about the lines in `seq` file may have trailing spaces. I am gonna remove my answer.

Comment: I selected a different answer as best solution given the use of awk, but I appreciate the simplicity of this. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Ed Mortan and Kent, I will not edit my answer since I feel your comments are valuable, let people read your comments too, Thanks once again guys..

Comment: @user3328689 Actually Ed's `awk` approach is very nice, since expected output mentioned was different so I answered this.